# Get the node name for xpath in Robot Framework

Tags: xpath, robotframework

Can't find the solution to my issue.
I have nodes to be identified, I mean - I have to get nodes names for following case:

```
<content-scope scope-data="scopeData">
  <link-group data="scopeData[0]">
  <text-img data="scopeData[1]">
</content-scope>
```

When I'm using following syntax (FirePath, directly from browser)

```
name((//content-scope[@scope-data='scopeData']/*)[1])
```

or

```
name((//content-scope[@scope-data='scopeData']/*)[2])
```

then I get node name ( link-group and text-img).

In robot-framework it doesn't work with keywords Get Text or Get Value. I get message:
"InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression name((//content-scope[@scope-data='scopeData']/*)[1]) because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.157)"

Here is a RF code (little simplified):

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Cards keywords library
Library           ExtendedSelenium2Library
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
${cardsXpathNameStart}    xpath=name(//content-scope[@scope-data='scopeData']/*)[
${index}          1

*** Test Cases ***
Getting Card Xpath Type
    Get Card Xpath Type

*** Keywords ***
Get Card Xpath Type
    : FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    1    2
    \    ${cardXpathType}    Get Text    ${cardsXpathNameStart}${index}]
    \    Log    ${cardXpathType}
```

How to build correct xpath which is interpreted by RF or which keyword should be used?

Comment: You say you're looking for name but your example shows an attribute called data which you're hoping to get the value for, is this correct?  Is there any IDs for these or can you create IDs to go in?

Comment: Yes,  I need to get the name (because of lack of ID, I can't create it) and next to build the xpath.

Comment: I don't understand though, your example doesn't include name?  Can you please post the actual example you're working with.  So far it's hard to understand

Comment: It's my actual example ;) Put simply - I have always element "content-scope" which should have various elements - in my example: link-group and text-img. Because of lack of id, I have to recognize them first by name (I don't really know what and how many elements I can meet) and then build proper xpath and finally do some specific actions (based on those elements names). If it is still unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Zeebee, if that is your full example, link-group and text-img do not have a name, therefore you of course cannot pick them out.  Do you mean you want the value for 'Data' for both of these elements?

You also try to get name for content-scope, as per your example, this also does not exist.  Can you work with your development team to add names or ids?

Comment: Hi shicky, but... I can get the name with using name((//content-scope[@scope-data='scopeData']/*)[1]) from browser (FirePath). So - it is possible to count all the elements for node "content-scope", then get the name each of them with loop. But in robot framework something is doesn't work...

Comment: @shicky: I think the confusion here is that Zeebee doesn't mean a `name` attribute, but rather the name of the element, e.g. `link-group`.

Comment: @Zeebee can you show us the exact code in Robot Framework that throws the error? Are you following the example code at http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Example ?

Comment: @LarsH - I've edited my post with a piece of code :) I've looked into XML library, but I've found no answer...

Comment: OK. Your question talks about `name((//...` in FirePath, but your code shows `name(//...` (only one left-parenthesis). Which could explain your error. Is that just a copy-n-paste mistake or is it actually only one left-paren in your code?

Comment: First, I'm finding how many elements is in //content-scope[@scope-data='scopeData'] node. Next I'm building (in loop) xpaths for each element, so it lookes like: name(//content-scope[@scope-data='scopeData']/*)[ index ]. Literally, xpath for first element should be like the following (it works in firepath): name((//content-scope[@scope-data='scopeData']/*)[1]). I've made a mistake with copy'n'paste the code. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution from WarBar (google groups, robotframework-users):

RF code:

```
Open Browser    file:///D:/temp/rf/a.html   
${elements} Get Webelements //content-scope[@scope-data='scopeData']/*
log ${elements[0].tag_name}
```

gives result:

```
20150826 10:37:37.551 :  INFO : Creating an instance of the Firefox WebDriver
20150826 10:37:40.326 :  INFO : Opening url 'file:///D:/temp/rf/a.html'
20150826 10:37:40.474 :  INFO : ${elements} = [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x03FCBA10>]
20150826 10:37:40.485 :  INFO : link-group
```